# WindowsForms в visual studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

При попытках компиляции C# высвечивается ошибка, что комп не знает что такое `System.Windows.Forms` Как его добавить в сборку, решений в интернете не нашел

> Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "RegistryKey" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: Проект под какую платформу? Небось, Core.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov именно он

Comment: А в core разве есть винформы?

Comment: Не кажется странным использование в современном Core - возможности Forms? Вам нужно что то вроде [этого](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, действительно помогло, от винформ нужно было именно это, конечно пришлось избавится от одного единственного меседж бокса, но это пустяки, да и не особо нужен он там был, можете оформить как ответ, я отмечу и плюсик обязательно поставлю

Comment: В [.NET Core 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/) будут добавлены Desktop packs - поддержка десктопных GUI - WinForms, WPF, UWP.

Comment: Вот когда они уже ̶п̶о̶р̶а̶б̶о̶т̶я̶т̶ ̶п̶л̶а̶н̶е̶т̶у̶ перенесут GUI на линукс? Так не хочется Qt изучать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как по мне - подключение возможностей от старых "технологий" в новые - это не рациональная трата ресурсов и времени. При выходе чего то нового, всегда необходимые функции переписывают.

В вашем случае нужно использовать что то вроде [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/) (официальной библиотеки от Microsoft, которая дает возможность работы с реестром в .Net Core).

Но, учтите одно - вы потеряете скорей всего кроссплатформенность!